# Can I use two shields and get the AC bonus from both?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, shield

The question title sums it up fairly quickly. If a character is wielding two shields, one in each hand, does she gain the shield bonus to AC from both, or only the higher one? And where in RAW is this written?

Answer (score 10):

Two shields do not stack. They both offer a shield bonus to your armor class, and like bonuses only overlap.

You can find the rule stated clearly here: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor#TOC-Armor-Shield-Bonus

Comment: Note that although the AC bonuses don't stack, the shield other properties can stack. For example you can have an interest in wearing a +5 shield and a +1 shield of fire resistance, the full set giving +5 to AC and the fire resistance.

Comment: True... you could also spike the shields, and enchant the shield spikes with non-numeric weapon properties. If you wanted.

Answer (score -6):

Shield bonuses do not stack with other *effects* that grant a shield bonus, but nothing says that the bonuses from *two* shields do not stack. The rules on [Armor/Shield Bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor#TOC-Armor-Shield-Bonus) says

> Each type of armor grants an armor bonus to Armor Class, while shields grant a shield bonus to Armor Class. The armor bonus from a suit of armor doesn't stack with other effects or items that grant an armor bonus. Similarly, **the shield bonus from a shield doesn't stack with other effects that grant a shield bonus.**

(Emphasis mine.) So while a breastplate doesn't stack with a chain shirt, two shields provide bonuses and aren't themselves effects.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I edited your answer so that it fits the site's guidelines. (It looks like this answer may've originally been an attempt to comment on The Amused Muse's [answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69110/8610), but that option was unavailable. ) With that in mind, it might be a good idea to review [bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus). Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: This is factual incorrect. -1. Any named bonus does not stack with a bonus of the same name. Shields are no exception.

Comment: If the shield bonus from a shield doesn't stack with other effects that grant a shield bonus, then the effect of the first shield won't stack with the effect of the second shield.